# Select attribute value with jQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to select attriute value with jQuery/CSS

```
<dt onclick="GomageNavigation.navigationOpenFilter('price-left');">
```

As regular it must be `db[onclick="GomageNavigation.navigationOpenFilter('price-left')"]`
but is not working. Any idea?

Comment: why not just give it an id or class?

Comment: Selecting an element that has a specific `onclick` attribute? That's very _fragile_ and a **bad practice**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `dt`, not `db` also missing double quote at the end

Change

```
db[onclick="GomageNavigation.navigationOpenFilter('price-left')]
```

to

```
  dt[onclick="GomageNavigation.navigationOpenFilter('price-left');"]
// ^here                     also missing quote and semicolum    ^^
```

You need to escape the quotes when selecting in jQuery so it would look like this

```
$("dt[onclick=\"GomageNavigation.navigationOpenFilter('price-left');\"]")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wQg5v/)

Comment: i saw the missing quote. However this is not working

Comment: @Stan updated answer you were missing semicolum aswell